# Android - CollapsingToolbarLayout display menu items only on top

Tags: android

I try to hide menu items when the CollapsingToolbarLayout is open.

I've do this: XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.compafone.app.ViewNews">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_view_news" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" android:src="@drawable/chatboxes" />
```

And this is the XML menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context="com.compafone.app.ViewNews">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_comments"
    android:title="Comments"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:icon="@drawable/chatboxes"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:title="Partager"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Then, this is the Java activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_news);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.arrowleft);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    //On récupère l'intent
    Intent i = getIntent();
    id = i.getStringExtra("ID");

    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Compafone");
    appbar = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);

    new NewsListActivityLoad().execute();


    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.news_title);
    content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.news_content);

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu resource
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view_news, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    //mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
            this.finish();
            this.overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_comments:
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            //Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, comments.class);
            try {
                //intent3.putExtra(Intent_ID, intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PROJET));
                //intent3.putExtra(Intent_SUCCES, "null");
                //startActivity(intent3);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("notFoundProject", "Le projet n'existe pas");
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_share:
            //doShare(shareintent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So, I want to hide items from menu and display items only when users scroll down (When toolbar is in normal size, so display items at the same time when toolbar title is show in the toolbar).

Sorry for bad english, thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution yet?

Comment: No... I didn't find solution yet ...